# jdbc transaction management : when releasing resources and distributed transactions

Tags: java, jdbc, transactions

hello
i'm a beginner java developer and this is one question in a list i'm posting since i've started porting a very old web service . I'm trying to improve the access to db and i'm finding a lot of code i believe migth be dangerous, but being not so experienced with java i cannot be sure .
Actually i've a class which manages the db connection and holds static references to a connection and a statement objects  : it exposes an "openDb" method which initializes the sql connection class member variable.

Problem number 1 : the class member variables are static, what is going to happen if the openDb is called multiple time and the first (for example) instance of the class is still executing a query?

the above class expose a method name "closeDb" which releases all resources (connection and statement both static members! ) and a "closeStatement" method which release only the statement member, and is used externally.

Problem number 2 : stements and resultset must be closed after a transaction committ/rollback or can be closed immediatly?

Still the same class handles the commit/rollback exposing some methods (to set autocommit to false, to commit or rollback ) . An instance of this class is passed to other classes instance (for example the usual employee department classes )  which execute their own queries on the db and finally the commit/rollback is called by the connection manager class . Is this "architecture" correct or do you see any danger in it ?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a **very** bad design and the observations you make concerning the static variables are correct. If one thread calls `openDb` and another thread does the same, things will go wrong. Maybe this happens not all the time which makes this hard to debug.

Concerning problem nr. 2: you should close things once you're done with them. This way you don't keep resources occupied unnecesary. So when you have read all (necessary) data from a result set, close it. It's also not a good idea to have statements and result sets escape the transaction boundary. So instead of:

```
begin transaction
  open result set
commit transaction
read from result set
```

you should have:

```
begin transaction
  open result set
  read from result set
commit transaction
```

To make the picture complete, you should always have the following pattern when using transactions:

```
begin transaction
  open connection
    read/modify data
  close connection
commit transaction
```

The `open connection`/`close connection` combination may occur multiple times within one transaction.

**EDIT**: To complete the picture even more: in the usual scenario, your application has several layers (e.g. UI, business, data). Transactions are usually started and committed inside the business layer. From the business layer you call one or more data layer methods that become a part of the transaction:

```
// Inside business layer:
public void businessMethod(...) {
    try {
        // Begin transaction.
        dataMethod1(...);
        dataMethod2(...);
        ...
        // Commit transaction.
    }
    catch (...) {
    }
}

// Inside data layer.
public void dataMethod1(...) {
    // Open connection.
    try {
        // Get data from database.
        // Manipulate data.
    }
    finally {
        // Close connection.
    }
}
```

Some additional notes:

- The transaction commit is the final statement inside the try/catch (if you want to return data from your method, it can be followed by a return statement). This ensures that the transaction only commits when *everything* is ok (i.e. no exception thrown).
- The connection close is inside the finally part of the try statement. This ensures that it is always closed, no matter what happens inside your data method.

Comment: thank you very much for your fast and clear answer, one more thing : you say open/close connection may happen multiple times, but i suppose it's always the same connection. What about opening different connection inside the same transaction ? will the second conection causes an exception or will the transaction affect only the connection it's associated to ?

Comment: The second connection will not cause an exception. It will only run inside the same transaction. You shouldn't worry about reusing the same connection but simply open a new connection when you need one. JDBC uses a connection pool so creating a new connection has hardly any performance impact.

Comment: the final two questions : when you say "will run inside the same transaction" do you mean the 2nd connection is part of the 1st connection transaction or the 2nd connection will work indipendently from 1st ? And what's the better strategy for jdbc connections provided by a datasource : open and close connection continuosly or try to use the less number of them (the first option i suppose : not to keep resources occupied )

Comment: This depends on your application design and what makes more sense. If you're inside a single method and you need to go to the database multiple times inside this method, I would use one connection. If your transaction spans multiple method calls, you should open a connection inside each method. I'll add some more info to my answer to illustrate this scenario.

Comment: sorry to bother you so much i meant the following case :  conn1.setAutocommit(false); stmt1 = conn1.createstatement(); ... accessing db one or more time .. localhelperMethod1(); localhelpermethod2(); ... conn1.commit();    if the class local helper methods access db only to retrieve data , their inner connections will be enlisted into conn1 transaction or will be indipendent ? and should i pass them conn1 or can i get their own connection from datasource. thank again for your answers

Comment: Hm, not absolutely sure. I thought you were using the Java Transaction API. I think both helper methods will enlist in the same transactions..